# Could I use a 3GS as test phone for iOS6?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I am making an app for iOS 6.

I have a Mac, but I'm locked into an Android phone for the next year, and really don't want the monthly expense of an iPhone from a regular carrier.

I can get a 3GS for around $200 and then use a pay-as-I-go service for my testing. Will this phone be a good 'test subject' for making iOS apps?

Comment: Why not get a used iPod touch instead of a phone you don't need? Just make sure it is a 4th or 5th gen iPod touch so it can run iOS 6.

Comment: Have I provided a satisfactory answer?

Answer (score 4):

### Yes.

However, there are several things to keep in mind:

1. The 3GS *is* four generations behind, so it *is* slower. This can be a good thing - any app that runs fast on a 3GS will run fast on later hardware.
2. Because of this, there are fewer iOS 6 features that it can use. Most of them are user-facing, though, and not API stuff.
3. The 3GS doesn't have a Retina display, so you will have to use the iOS simulator for Retina testing.

If these drawbacks don't bother you any (Retina display is the biggest one), **don't use pay-as-you-go**! (if you have Wi-Fi). The phone's GPS will still work, and it can still connect to WiFi without a cell plan. Since you say you already have a phone, you don't need voice or data on a dev device.

Just buy one off of Craigslist for around $100-150, and you will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. It actually wouldn't be a bad idea at all because it is the slowest hardware that can run your app, so if it runs efficiently and well (within memory constraints and CPU speed) then you should be in good shape for better hardware! Also you can look at the iPod touch if you don't need any GPS or phone functionalities. One thing you won't get to test on device though is retina graphics (which does make a huge difference).